# Python 3 import class from subfolder problem

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have a strange problem regarding import classes from subfolders.

I'm using `Python 3.6`, therefore an `__init__.py` should be not required in the subfolders.

I have the following file structure:

```sh
root
├── script.py (main)
└── custom
    ├── class1.py
    └── class2.py
```

---

This is `script.py`:

```py
from custom.class1 import Class1
from custom.class2 import Class2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl1 = Class1()
    cl2 = Class2()
```

---

This is `class1.py`:

```py
class Class1():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Class1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl1 = Class1()
```

---

This is `class2.py`, which imports also class1:

```py
from class1 import Class1

class Class2():
    def __init__(self):
        cl1 = Class1()
        print('Class2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl2 = Class2()
```

---

And now the problem:

It works without error, when i am running `python class1.py` in the `custom` subfolder.

It works without error, when i am running `python class2.py` in the `custom` subfolder.

But when i am running `python script.py` in the `root` folder, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File .... in <module>
    from custom.class2 import Class2
  File .... line 1, in <module>
    from class1 import Class1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class1'
```

How can this be fixed in a way, that the scripts in the `custom` subfolders can be run on its own and also the script in the `root` folder works?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are running `custom.class2` inside of `script.py`, which means while running `custom.class2`, you are still in the `root` directory.

To fix this, you should replace `from class1 import Class1` from `class2.py` with `from custom.class1 import Class1`.

If you need to be able to run the file from any working directory, you may replace it's contents with this:

```
import os
import sys

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
if not path in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from class1 import Class1

class Class2():
    def __init__(self):
        cl1 = Class1()
        print('Class2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl2 = Class2()
```

The code adds the file's path in to the `sys.path` list, which holds different paths from which you can import modules.

Comment: Thanks for the code example. Really annoying that python cannot handle this itself. I am wondering how to run unit tests with this path hell...

Comment: That shouldn't be too much of a problem as the current working directory isn't changing, it's going to be the same, it's just adding a path which it should check whenever a module can't be found. I'll notify you if I find a "cleaner" answer.